file_rego_versions field is not retained in .manifest file after performing opa build command
I want to support multiple rego versions of policies in my application. I found that the manifest **file_rego_versions **field in the manifest file provided in the link [https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/management-bundles/] shown below
{
  "revision" : "0",
  "rego_version": 1,
  "file_rego_versions": {
    "/foo/*.rego": 0,
    "/policy1.rego": 0
  }
}  

serves the purpose. After I place the .manifest in the policies folder and execute opa build command [opa build -b policies/ -o bundle.tar.gz] it generates a bundle tar file as output. If I extract the bundler.tar.gz and check the .manifest file "tar -axf bundle.tar.gz /.manifest -O" the contents look like this {"revision":"0","roots":[""],"rego_version":1}  the section file_rego_versions is removed. How to retain it after opa build command?
mkdir policies
under policies create file access_policy.rego
access_policy.rego contents:
package example

default validate_policy = false

validate_policy {
        input.policyType == "onap.test.opa"
        input.policyVersion >= 1
        input.taskLogic != null
        input.address.zip >= 12345
        input.address.apt.doornum >= 101
        input.phone.number >= 1000000
}

under policies create a .manifest file
.manifest contents
{
  "revision":"2",
  "roots":["example"],
  "rego_version": 0,
  "file_rego_versions": {
    "/access_policy.rego": 0
  }
}

cd policies;       
opa build -b . -o /tmp/bundle.tar.gz;
cd /tmp;
tar -axf bundle2.tar.gz /.manifest -O

{"revision":"2","roots":["example"],"rego_version":0}


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

When OPA builds a bundle and is provided a path with the -b flag, it should respect any existing .manifest file and the file_rego_versions entries contained therein. However, OPA will not copy the values as-is. Instead, a new list will be constructed based on the rego files that are put into the new bundle (aided by the pre-existing .manifest).
In your access_policy.rego example, this file isn't explicitly included in the manifest file since its rego version is already covered by the bundle's version ("rego_version": 0).
Using your first manifest
{
  "revision" : "0",
  "rego_version": 1,
  "file_rego_versions": {
    "/foo/*.rego": 0,
    "/policy1.rego": 0
  }
}  

you should see entries in the new bundles manifests file_rego_versions list if the build input indeed contains rego files inside the foo folder, and/or if there is a policy1.rego file in the root of the provided build path.
So, to recap: to retain file_rego_versions entries, the files listed there must both exist, and their specified version must differ from that of rego_version. Furthermore, individual file paths might get mutated; e.g. wildcards (*/**) might be replaced with explicit path components extrapolated during the build.
Hope this helps!
